Apache loading issue
I have been trying to load apache using localhost, and some other server-based applications, like localhost/joomla, localhost/moodle, etc. But I am not able to load either apache or the above applications. It is showing:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
But some applications like localhost/phpmyadmin, localhost/vufind are running successfully. Andn other applications running in various ports like localhost:2001, localhost:8080, are also running. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Have a look at /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf: that is a symlink to /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf, which contains the configuration for phpMyAdmin as loaded by Apache; if I understood correctly, you want to look into the Alias directive, which allows to map a URL path to a location in the filesystem. You should create a configuration file for each application that doesn't natively include this configuration (unlike phpMyAdmin), using the Alias directive as phpMyAdmin does.

Please edit your question and update it with more details: Your /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf configuration file. How were joomla and moodle installed? The output of apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES can be useful too.
